# Set cell highlight colors dynamically Android Times Square CalendarView

Tags: android, android-calendar, calendarview

I am using [Android Times Square](https://github.com/square/android-times-square/) for a customizable CalendarView. I want to highlight two sets of dates with different colors. Right now I can highlight the dates in both the set with only one color using the following in xml

```
  <color name="calendar_highlighted_day_bg">#00A593</color>
```

Calendar class

```
    List<DateTime> set1 = new List<DateTime>{date1, date2, date3};
    List<DateTime> set2 = new List<DateTime>{date4, date5, date6};
calendarView.HighlightDates(set1);
calendarView.HighlightDates(set2);
```

How can I apply a different color highlight to set2?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below

In MainActivity

```
 GridView grid;
ImageView left,right;
TextView mon,yr;
MyCalendarAdapter adapter2;
ArrayList<String> weeks = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> calendars = new ArrayList<>();
String[] months= {"JANUARY","FEBRUARY","MARCH","APRIL","MAY","JUNE","JULY","AUGUST","SEPTEMBER","OCTOBER",
"NOVEMBER","DECEMBER"};
private int month,year;
Date d;
Calendar c;
private String dayOfTheWeek;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance);
    empId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("EmpID");

    weeks.add("SUN");
    weeks.add("MON");
    weeks.add("TUE");
    weeks.add("WED");
    weeks.add("THU");
    weeks.add("FRI");
    weeks.add("SAT");

// add day of month you want to highlight
    calendars.add(5);
    calendars.add(10);
    calendars.add(25);
    grid =  findViewById(R.id.grid);
    left =  findViewById(R.id.left);
    right =  findViewById(R.id.right);
    mon =  findViewById(R.id.mon);
    yr =  findViewById(R.id.yr);



    c = Calendar.getInstance();
     month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
     d = new Date();
     d.setDate(1);
     dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(d).toUpperCase();
    Log.d("FIRSTDAY",""+dayOfTheWeek);
    getAttendance(String.valueOf(year), String.format("%02d",(month+1)));
    adapter2= new MyCalendarAdapter(c,weeks.indexOf(dayOfTheWeek),calendars);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter2);
    mon.setText(months[month]);
    yr.setText(""+year);

    left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            calendars.clear();
            if(month==0)
            {
                month=11;
                year--;
            }
            else {
                month--;
            }
            d.setMonth(month);
            d.setYear(year);
            c.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
            c.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
            mon.setText(months[month]);
            yr.setText(""+year);
            dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(d).toUpperCase();
            Log.d("FIRSTDAY",""+dayOfTheWeek);
            int w= weeks.indexOf(dayOfTheWeek);
            if(w==0)
            {
                adapter2= new MyCalendarAdapter(c,6,calendars);
            }
            else {
                adapter2= new MyCalendarAdapter(c,w-1,calendars);
            }
            grid.setAdapter(adapter2);
            getAttendance(String.valueOf(year), String.format("%02d",(month+1)));
        }
    });

    right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calendars.clear();
            if(month==11)
            {
                month=0;
                year++;
            }
            else {
                month++;
            }

            d.setMonth(month);
            d.setYear(year);
            c.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
            c.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
            mon.setText(months[month]);
            yr.setText(""+year);
            dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(d).toUpperCase();
            Log.d("FIRSTDAY",""+dayOfTheWeek);
            int w= weeks.indexOf(dayOfTheWeek);
            if(w==0)
            {
                adapter2= new MyCalendarAdapter(c,6,calendars);
            }
            else {
                adapter2= new MyCalendarAdapter(c,w-1,calendars);
            }
            grid.setAdapter(adapter2);
            getAttendance(String.valueOf(year),String.format("%02d",(month+1)));
        }
    });

}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/app_bg"
<LinearLayout
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/_14sdp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >
    <LinearLayout
       android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
       android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <com.sixsquare.sams.utils.CalendarText
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:id="@+id/mon"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text=""/>
            <com.sixsquare.sams.utils.CalendarText
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:id="@+id/yr"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text=""/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >
        <com.sixsquare.sams.utils.CalendarText
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="SUN"/>
        <com.sixsquare.sams.utils.CalendarText
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="MON"/>
        <com.sixsquare.sams.utils.CalendarText
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="TUE"/>
        <com.sixsquare.sams.utils.CalendarText
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="WED"/>
        <com.sixsquare.sams.utils.CalendarText
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="THU"/>
        <com.sixsquare.sams.utils.CalendarText
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="FRI"/>
        <com.sixsquare.sams.utils.CalendarText
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="SAT"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <GridView
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></GridView>
    <!--<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager-->

        <!--android:id="@+id/pager"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_weight="1"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>-->
</LinearLayout>
```

> Create class MyCalendarAdapter

```
        import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import com.sixsquare.sams.R;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Calendar;

public class MyCalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   Calendar c;
    ArrayList<Integer> calendars;
    int ct;
    public MyCalendarAdapter(Calendar c,int ct,ArrayList<Integer> calendars) {
        this.c = c;
        this.ct= ct;
        this.calendars= calendars;
        Log.d("FIRSTDAY",""+ct);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        int x=getMonthDays(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1,c.get(Calendar.YEAR))+ct;
//        Log.d("FIRSTDAY",""+x);
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int p, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_calendar, parent, false);
        TextView text = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(parent.getContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/fontastique.ttf"));
        int position= p+1-ct;
        if(position>0) {

            text.setText("" + position);
            if(calendars.contains(position))
            {
                text.setTextColor(parent.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circular_shape);
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
    public static int getMonthDays(int month, int year) {
        int daysInMonth ;
        if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
            daysInMonth = 30;
        }
        else {
            if (month == 2) {
                daysInMonth = (year % 4 == 0) ? 29 : 28;
            } else {
                daysInMonth = 31;
            }
        }
//        Log.d("FIRSTDAY","days "+daysInMonth);
        return daysInMonth;
    }
}
```

my_calendar.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/_3sdp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_32sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_32sdp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```